# Custom function don't read vectors

Tags: r

I have this custom function to show the combinations:

```
x<-function(a,b){

  ncol(combn(a,b))

}

combinations<-numeric()

for(i in 0:12){
    combinations<-c(combinations,x(12,i))
}

combinations
```

It works, but I want to know if it's possible to do something simpler, like this:

```
x<-function(a,b){

  ncol(combn(a,b))

}

x(12,0:12)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of combinations of size `k` from a set of size `n` can be computed with `choose(n, k)` in R, and if you have multiple `k` values you can just pass in a vector for `k`. Therefore your code can be simplified to:

```
choose(12, 0:12)
#  [1]   1  12  66 220 495 792 924 792 495 220  66  12   1
```